# how to change extension in my sql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a website with over 4000 images and all my images are in sql data base i use phpMyAdmin.
All my images are saved as .jpg files. So my web site is slow because jpg images size is to big. I converted my images to webP so my images now are in the same quality but low file size.
My problem is when i changed my images in the root folder all the jpg images are now .webp images but in the sql data base my images are listed as .jpg files. I need a fast way to change all my 4000 images from jpg to webP extensions in sql data base.
To display my images I use this code

```
<img src="../<?php echo $row["p_image"]; ?>"  style="width:100%" ></a>
```

so i cant change it in the code form jpg to webp. I need to change the name of the images in data base for example image1.jpg to image1.webp.
(My web site is coded in html, php, java and sql)
Thank You

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a database client. It is not a database.

Comment: Why not use `REPLACE()` in MySQL?

Comment: Go to `phpMyAdmin`, click on `SQL` and then modify this to suit: `UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, '.jpg', '.webp')`